# NLP: Way to efficiently compare and identify trends between text

Tags: nlp, text-mining

Are there algorithms or methods in which common trends/themes between text items could be evaluated?

For example let's say that there are four data points (text entries):

- "I found school very stressful today"
- "The test in physics was pretty easy."
- "My physics test wasn't challenging at all"
- "Everyone left early because the physics test was straight-forward and we finished it early."

Based on those four entries the first one is an outlier and has no relation to the rest but the other three mention how the "physics test" was easy (more generally, the other three express a positive sentiment around the "physics test").

Are there methods to extract the common thread between related sentences? These sentences are totally open ended and aren't restricted to simply expressing sentiment about an object - they could be talking about anything.

I understand this is a fairly broad question but I thought I'd ask it so see if people know of existing solutions or ways people have tackled this problem in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible solution can be - generate sentence representation (Sent2Vec) first and then compare those representations.

There are many approaches to generate a sentence embedding of a English sentence. One of the popular approach is [skip-though vectors](https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts). Just convert the sentence to vector and then use cosine similarity to compare sentences.

You can also use those sentence embeddings to train a neural network to accomplish your target task.

Comment: That looks interesting - thanks! It appears that the Sent2Vec process would help accomplish the first part of my task - but I'm also looking for a way to actually identify what in specific are the relations between the sentences (i.e. they both reference "physics test" with the adjective "easy")

Comment: @abagshaw then you need sentence parsing and extracting the noun phrases, then generate phrase embedding and compare them all possible pair. you should get some intuition to identify relationship between the keywords then!

Comment: That's what I was thinking...but I'm not sure if that will be able to scale to comparing tens/hundreds of thousands of sentences.

Comment: @abagshaw it depends on model design. if you have more examples, that is a good news because you can train a deep neural model to accomplish your target task!